# Jmeter - performance plugin

Tags: performance, jmeter, jenkins-plugins, performance-testing

I am using Performance plugin in Jenkins for my Jmeter tests. It allows me to fail a build either based on relative threshold or error threshold. But I want to fail a build doing both i.e.

- compare with the previous build and if the relative difference is more than 80%, fail the build
- If the build has any errors, fail the build.

How do i achieve both?

Comment: Why do you want to compare it with previous build? This is a dangerous approach, which can make you miss slow, gradual, long-term degradation of performance. As long as it degrades just a bit with every run, builds will be marked as passed. Don't you want switch to comparison of response times with exact value? E.g. fail build if a) there are any failures OR b) average response times are above certain value?

Comment: Thanks! that makes sense. I just finished adding some beanshell script to fail if the average response time is greater than 3 secs per page

Comment: Just for you to know, there is a tool which can handle this for you:

https://github.com/automatictester/lightning/wiki/Usage-Example

This tool offers you more than only average response time verification, check the wiki for more information.